# Multilingual App Toolkit - get resource - MissingManifestResourceException

Tags: c#, wpf, embedded-resource, multilingual, multilingual-app-toolkit

I need help with Multilingual App Toolkit (MAT) and exactly when geting a particular translations.

For example:
I have Resources.resx and I add 2 languages (using MAT).
The application works correctly if i use WPF and binding by XAML like:

```
<MenuItem Header="{x:Static prop:Resources.Standard_Settings}">
```

But when i want add get some resource by code.
I tried:

```
ResourceManager resourcesManager = new ResourceManager("Resources", typeof(MainWindow).Assembly);
var myResource = resourcesManager.GetString("Standard_Play");
```

But it caused exception:

```
MissingManifestResourceException
```

Thanks for all.

Comment: First you need add culture info to resource (i don't know why it doesn't work automatically) and use auto-generated member.

For example:

    ResourcesNamespace.ResourcesClass.Culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

If you don't know: "ResourcesNamespace" or "ResourcesClass" you can expand the repository file and open auto-generated resource class.

And now if u want some resource from any resource you can do this:

    ResourceManager resourcesManager = ResourcesNamespace.ResourcesClass.ResourceManager;
    var resource = resourcesManager.GetString("Standard_Play");